# How to update translation cakephp but not main table

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I have added translate behaviour to a model, the model comes here

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Category extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = "Product";
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Translate' => array(
            'name','folder','show'
        )
    );
    public $name = "Category";

    public $translateModel = 'KeyTranslate';
}
```

And heres the controller for updating the model

```
public function admin_edit_translate($id,$locale)
    {

    $this->Category->locale = $locale;          
    $category = $this->Category->findById($id);

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->Category->id = $id;
        if ($this->Category->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Category translate has been updated');
            //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit',$id));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update category');
        }
    }
    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $category;
    }
    }
```

My Problem is that i have a name field in the categories database and when i update or create a new translation it gets updated with the translated value. How do i avoid that

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Model::locale` value to set code language for save in database

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the TranslateBehavior uses callbacks like beforeSave and afterSave to save translated content, so it needs to let the model's save operation continue and thus will contain the last translated content.

You could get around this by tricking the TranslateBehavior into thinking the model is saving something by calling the beforeSave and afterSave like this:

```
$Model = $this->Category;

$Model->create($this->request->data);
$Model->locale = $locale;

$beforeSave = $Model->Behaviors->Translate->beforeSave($Model, array(
    array(
        'callbacks' => true
    )
));

if($beforeSave) {
    $Model->id = $id;
    $Model->Behaviors->Translate->afterSave($Model, true);
}
```

This way the translation will be saved and the main table will be left untouched. Might not be the best way to save translations though. Why do you need to leave the main table untouched?

Answer (score 0):

Callback `Behavior::beforeSave` is before `Model::beforeSave`...

but, the simplest way to modify data in `Model::beforeSave` before `Behavior::beforeSave` before realy saving is:

```
$this->Behaviors->Behavior_Name->runtime[Model_Name]['beforeSave'][Field_Name] = '...';
```