# CakePHP TranslateBehavior saving to both i18n table and model table

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I have a very simple test setup - one table (dingos) from which I've baked model, controller and views. The model has two fields, title and description, and I've added this to the model file, for translations:

```
var $actsAs = array('Translate' => array('title', 'description'));
```

Adding a new row to the model table (via the baked view/action ) is fine, it results in two new rows in i18n (title and description) using the current locale.

I then edit this but have added a line to the baked edit action:

```
$this->Dingo->locale = 'ru_ru'; 
if ($this->Dingo->save($this->request->data)) {
    // etc etc
```

Two news rows (title, description) are added to i18n with the correct foreign key. However, the row in the dingos table is **also** updated. The (admittedly sparse) documentation seems to suggest that only i18n would be affected, so is this incorrect, have I overlooked something?

Thanks,

Toby

**UPDATE**
Seems to be the same issue reported here:
"[How to update translation cakephp but not main table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677279/how-to-update-translation-cakephp-but-not-main-table)"

Comment: If you didn't twice the same content, You can remove fields from main Model

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, apparently this is how it should work.

I don't fully understand this (I imagined the relationship between model table and i18n table was analogous to the *.pot vs *.po relationship, but Mark Storey responded on the CakePHP issue tracker ([here](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/3737-TranslateBehavior-saves-to-both-i18n-and-model-table)).

**UPDATE**
As Mark points out, this is [documented](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html#defining-the-fields). I am a fool.